# JxBrowser view is gone when stage is hidden

Tags: java, javafx, jxbrowser

I have used jxbrowser in my javafx app as this :

```
public class Main extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;

private Browser browser;

private boolean firstMinimize;

private TrayIcon trayIcon;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(args);

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

    firstMinimize = true;

    Platform.setImplicitExit(false);

    createTrayIcon();

    browser = new Browser();

    BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView(browser);

    StackPane pane = new StackPane();

    pane.getChildren().add(browserView);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 380, 500);

    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.show();

    browser.addRenderListener(new RenderAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onRenderGone(RenderEvent event) {

            System.out.println("here called...");

            Browser browser = event.getBrowser();
            // Restore Browser instance by loading the same URL
            browser.loadURL(browser.getURL());
        }
    });

    initialize();

    // if not logged in

    showLogin();

}

public void initialize() {

    initCloseButton(primaryStage);

    initMinimizeButton(primaryStage);

}

public void initCloseButton(Stage primaryStage) {

    browser.registerFunction("Close", new BrowserFunction() {

        @Override
        public JSValue invoke(JSValue... args) {

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    closeToTray(primaryStage);

                }
            });

            return null;

        }

    });

}

public void initMinimizeButton(Stage primaryStage) {

    browser.registerFunction("Minimize", new BrowserFunction() {

        @Override
        public JSValue invoke(JSValue... args) {

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    primaryStage.setIconified(true);

                }
            });

            return null;

        }

    });

}


public void createTrayIcon() {

    if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {

        SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

        java.awt.Image image = null;

        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://www.digitalphotoartistry.com/rose1.jpg");

            image = ImageIO.read(url);

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            System.out.println(ex);

        }


        final ActionListener closeListener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {

                System.exit(0);

            }

        };

        final ActionListener showListener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {

                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

      //                            primaryStage.setOpacity(0);

                        primaryStage.show();

                    }

                });

            }

        };

        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();

        MenuItem showItem = new MenuItem("Show");
        showItem.addActionListener(showListener);
        popup.add(showItem);

        MenuItem closeItem = new MenuItem("Close");
        closeItem.addActionListener(closeListener);
        popup.add(closeItem);

        trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "RezRem", popup);

        trayIcon.addActionListener(showListener);

        try {

            tray.add(trayIcon);

        } catch (AWTException e) {

            System.err.println(e);

        }

    }

}

public void showMinimizeMessage() {

    if (firstMinimize) {

        trayIcon.displayMessage("some message",
                "Some other message.",
                TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);

        firstMinimize = false;

    }

}

private void closeToTray(Stage primaryStage) {

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override

        public void run() {

            if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {

     //                 primaryStage.setOpacity(0);

                primaryStage.hide();

                showMinimizeMessage();

            } 
            else {

                System.exit(0);

            }

        }
    });
}

public void showLogin() {

    browser.loadURL(Main.class.getResource("templates/login.html").toExternalForm());

    browser.registerFunction("Login", new BrowserFunction() {

        @Override
        public JSValue invoke(JSValue... args) {

            for (JSValue arg : args) {

                System.out.println("arg = " + arg.getString());

            }

            return JSValue.create("Hello!");

        }

    });

}

}
```

I have set close button to hide stage when clicked in function "closeToTray".(In order to minimize it to system tray) But then calling stage.show() brings up the browser but browser view is just a overall white, in other words, rendered page is gone this way. Here is a screenshot of before and after minimizing to system tray :
[Before clicking close btn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEEAH.jpg), [after clicking show from system tray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRKuG.jpg)

any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in [JxBrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser) 6.0.2. The fix will be available in next update that will be released in a week.